# SQL Rank query optimization

Tags: sql, optimization, rank

I have the following table structure for a table Player

```
Table Player {  
Long playerID;  
Long points;  
Long rank;  
}
```

Assuming that the playerID and the points have valid values, can I update the rank for all the players based on the number of points in a single query? If two people have the same number of points, they should tie for the rank.

I'm using hibernate, so cannot execute any queries with variables, so I came up with this query which is very inefficient. Can this be optimized to work with the constraints specified above?

```
update player g1 
    set g1.rank = 1 + 
    ((SELECT count(*) from 
    (select * from player) g2 
    where g2.points > g1.points))
```

Comment: You can edit your earlier question, and leave comments to ask for clarification on an answer. No need to open a new question ...

Comment: @meriton - That is what I did initially, but I was suggested to open a new question. Sorry if I did not abide by the conventions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MS SQL Server 2005+ T-SQL, I can recommend having a look at the fantastic **ROW_NUMBER(), RANK() AND DENSE_RANK(), and NTILE()** functions!

[Read more here about them](https://web.archive.org/web/20210512232142/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/010406-1.shtml)

Comment: They're also available in Oracle and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

There are four ranking function in SQL Server. ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK, and NTILE are use to return a ranking value for each row over the partition.

For difference between them with example check the URL given below

http://www.freshcodehub.com/Article/50/implement-ranking-functions-in-sql-server